# How to enable Partial Unification in Spark REPL with Scala 2.11.8?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, scala-2.11

I have Scala code written in Scala 2.11.12 using the partial-unification compiler option, which I would like to run in a Spark 2.2.2 REPL.

With a Spark version compiled against Scala 2.11.12 (i.e. 2.3+), this is possible in the Spark REPL via `:settings -Ypartial-unification`, and the code executes.

I want to run this on Spark 2.2.2, which is compiled against Scala 2.11.8.

To do this, I have downloaded the jar with the partial unification compiler plugin (source from: https://github.com/milessabin/si2712fix-plugin), which backports this setting.

I've played around with a Scala 2.11.8 REPL (adding jar to the classpath - seems too rudimentary) and haven't managed to get it working there (before trying to add it to Spark), and am asking if anyone knows how to do this or if adding a compiler setting to a REPL via a JAR is not possible.

Any other advice appreciated!